# How to merge duplicate collections

Tags: c#, array-merge

I am trying to merge duplicate meters and have come op with this method:

```
private IEnumerable<Meter> MergeDuplicateMeters(IEnumerable<Meter> meters)
    {
        var tmpMeters = meters.ToList();
        var duplicates = tmpMeters
            .GroupBy(m => m.MeterUID)
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
            .ToList();
        foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            var meter1 = duplicate.FirstOrDefault();
            var meter2 = duplicate.LastOrDefault();
            tmpMeters.Remove(meter1);
            tmpMeters.Remove(meter2);
            if (meter2.GsmData != null)
            {
                if (meter1.GsmData == null)
                {
                    meter1.GsmData = new List<GSMData>();
                }
                meter1.GsmData.AddRange(meter2.GsmData);
            }
            if (meter2.P2pMeterSession != null)
            {
                if (meter1.P2pMeterSession == null)
                {
                    meter1.P2pMeterSession = new List<P2PMeterSession>();
                }
                meter1.P2pMeterSession.AddRange(meter2.P2pMeterSession);
            }
            tmpMeters.Add(meter1);
        }
        return tmpMeters;
    }
```

the problem is that this way I can only merge one time but what if I want to merge every time a new list is read?

Comment: sorry forgot to put that in. It is C#

Comment: Have you considered using Linq's `Union` method?

Comment: @NathanA looks about right to me. Here's the MS documentation for Union with some good examples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: the meters can contain different properties fx one MeterUID could have a CellID while the duplicate MeterUID have SignalStrength. How would Union take care of that? @Nathan A